# Websphere MQ 7.1 Automatic Startup

Tags: ibm-mq

What is the best way to startup automatically Websphere MQ v7.1 queue managers during system startup? I see that there is a [SupportPac](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24016554) for it, just want to make sure this is the right one. We have MQ running over 64-bit Linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [SupportPac MSL1](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMSL1) is the correct one for Linux.

Some other UNIX flavors can use this SupportPac as-is or with modifications.  For Windows, specify the QMgr to be started automatically and the WMQ service will start it.

---

**Update 26 Sep 2017**
Responding to comments from byteborg, I checked and it seems IBM have removed SupportPac MSL1 for some reason, even from the list of withdrawn SupportPacs.

As it happens I'm at [MQTC](http://mqtechconference.com) this week and lots of IBMers from Hursley Lab are here so I'll ask then to restore it or put it on Github.  If they are able to do so, the internal review process to make that happen is extensive so it won't happen soon.  If that doesn't work, I'll see about getting permission to host it myself.  Stay tuned.

---

**Update 1 Oct 2017**
While at MQTC, Mark Taylor, the MQ Architect from IBM Hursley Labs, explained the removal of MSL1.  Basically, "it didn't work" according to Mark.  Instead, IBM have provided guidance in the form of an MQDev blog post *[Managing queue manager startup and shutdown on Linux with systemd](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/mq_linux_systemd?lang=en)*.  The post does pretty much what the headline says, and describes how to use systemd to start/stop MQ.  Please refer to that post for details.

Comment: IBM's web server throws a 410 Gone error upon request. A Google search for alternatives turned up nothing usable. Any hints?

Comment: @byteborg This would be appropriate as a new question. It is possible but unlikely that anyone will respond to a question about WAS posed in a comment on an answer buried in the [tag:ibm-mq] tag.

Comment: @T.Rob sorry for not being precise. The link to MSL1 is broken, that's what I wanted to say. Might it be that IBM has pulled this supportpac?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll ask Mark Taylor about getting some form of it restored. See updates in my reply.